# I want to read the CSV file from client and want to process in php any suggestions

Tags: php, jquery

I have csv file with data i want to read data without uploading it to the server, i have coded using php to read and process but i am not getting any notification to the user whether it is uploaded successfully and processed, i want to show once i upload the file using input type : file until it process it need to show as processing and after completed it need to show uploaded successfully but its not possible in PHP i used jquery but, i can read the data from csv but cant pass to php as parameter.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), i.e:

`persons.csv`

```
Kai Jim, Refsnes, Stavanger, Norway
Pedro, Lobito, Lisboa, Portugal
```

code:

```
$file = fopen("persons.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
```

The command above will output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Kai Jim
[1] => Refsnes
[2] => Stavanger
[3] => Norway
)
```

---

if you need to read every line on the file, you can use:

```
$file = fopen("persons.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  }
fclose($file);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Kai Jim
[1] => Refsnes
[2] => Stavanger
[3] => Norway
)
Array
(
[0] => Pedro
[1] => Lobito
[2] => Lisboa
[3] => Portugal
)
```

---

There's also [CSV data parser for PHP](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) and it's quite easy to use, i.e.:

```
require_once 'parsecsv.lib.php';
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->auto('persons.csv');
print_r($csv->data);
```

Comment: Hey Pedro Lobito thanks for your response, currently i m using the same method but the thing is i just want to change the button style using jquery i can read the data but need to show some notification to the user in the ui so its not possible only in PHP, what tried is i read the csv in jquery but not able to pass the data to php.

Comment: I think you should update your question to make it more clear about what you really need.